# Size classes: starting with Compact Regular and moving to Any Any rather than vice versa?

Tags: ios, xcode7, size-classes

I just started using size classes and while the generally advised approach seems to be to start out using Any Any size class and *then* adapt for other size classes, I started my project with Compact Regular and now when I go to Any Any I don't see the UI elements that I already added to Compact Regular in the Any Any size class.

So, in Compact Regular where I started my development, I can see my UImage and buttons, but as soon as I go to Any Any they are missing.

I understand that going from Any Any to Compact Regular would have preserved and carried over the UI elements- Is this correct?

Comment: Hi Luke, I asked about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33176675/xcode-7-pressing-down-on-uibutton-in-simulator-having-no-effect

Comment: okay, will take a look at that later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**! If you would have gone from Any/Any to Compact/Regular your UI elements would have been preserved, since the specific Compact/Regular is a subset of Any/Any.

But don't worry, you don't have to insert all UI elements once again. You just have to tick one checkbox. In the following pictures you can see a label in added in Compact/Regular and then carried over to Any/Any:

- the label is present in Compact/Regular:

[image]

- But not in Any/Any

[image]

- Select the label and check the `Installed` checkbox for the Any/Any sizeclass

[image]

- the label now shows up in Any/Any

[image]

- Unfortunately you have to do this for ALL connected constraints as well :/ But luckily you can just select multiple of elements / all elements in in the left tab and just change their sizeclass in one sweep.